# Is there a function or package in R that can get lambda of poisson distribution from quantile and probability?

Tags: r

for example, `F(X = 2 | lambda = 2.3) =  0.596` I know 2 and 0.596 and I would like to get lambda.

I know I can do it by numerical approximation algorithms.

However before I manually create a function, is there an existing function that I can simply use?

#### Update

It is a shame that I have to use numerical method. I had thought there is a popular well known analytic method / close form.

Comment: You *may* be able to do this mathematically rather than computationally: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution for the Poisson CDF and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function for further definitions ...

Comment: @BenBolker hmm, found this  http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/talks/poisson_2013.pdf

Comment: That's not what you want -- that's the inverse Poisson CDF, which is implemented as `qpois`.  I think you'll have to work it out yourself, but unless you need it to be *really* fast and accurate, @RichieCotton's answer will probably be just fine.

Comment: There could be an analytic solution, but I'm pleading Uwe's maxim: "Computers are cheap, and thinking hurts".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Optimization is probably the way to go with this.

```
f <- function(lambda) abs(ppois(2, lambda) - 0.5960388)
optimize(f, c(0, 10))
```

Or, as Ben B suggested,

```
f2 <- function(lambda) ppois(2, lambda) - 0.5960388
uniroot(f2, c(0, 10))
```

Comment: Do you mean `uniroot` rather than `optimize`?? (I think there's probably a nearly closed-form solution, or at least one that you can get just using `qgamma`, which is the scaled inverse-incomplete gamma function -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution for the Poisson CDF and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function for the definition of the incomplete Gamma function ...

Comment: (I see you used `abs()`, so `optimize` should work, but I think `f <- function(lambda) ppois(2,lambda) - 0.5960388); uniroot(f,0,10)` would work better ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Good spot.  I get confused with all the slightly different optimization functions.

Comment: @RichieCotton I'm struggling to recreate this result for non-cumulative poisson probabilities. So for instance, say mean bad eggs is 0.7, and you want to know the chance there are exactly 2, `dpois(2, 0.7)` gives 0.12. Then: `f <- function(lambda) abs(dpois(2, lambda) - 0.12)` and `optimize(f, c(0, 10))` gives 4.3 not 0.7. What am I doing wrong?